# Problem installing mssql-django from command line with pip

Tags: python, mssql-django

I am trying to install mssql-django with pip from the command line (Python 3.8 but I also tried 3.11 and Django 4.0.10):

pip install mssql-django --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

and this is the output I am obtaining:

Collecting mssql-django
ERROR: HTTP error 400 while getting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/12/9d60414b21ae1d348dfeefaea9f6591145f67ef11cde0d63da574fea0ff1/mssql_django-1.3-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=30b5338aca192d72999b05bc6bb6028d32dbb881586e
96dffebf73ad98c16a15 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mssql-django/)
ERROR: Could not install requirement mssql-django from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/12/9d60414b21ae1d348dfeefaea9f6591145f67ef11cde0d63da574fea0ff1/mssql_django-1.3-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=30b5338aca192d72999b05bc6bb
6028d32dbb881586e96dffebf73ad98c16a15 because of HTTP error 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/12/9d60414b21ae1d348dfeefaea9f6591145f67ef11cde0d63da574fea0ff1/mssql_django-1.3-py3-non
e-any.whl for URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/12/9d60414b21ae1d348dfeefaea9f6591145f67ef11cde0d63da574fea0ff1/mssql_django-1.3-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=30b5338aca192d72999b05bc6bb6028d32dbb881586e96dffebf73ad98c16a15
(from https://pypi.org/simple/mssql-django/)

I expected mssql-django to be installed. I could not find any similar threads but I tried adding the trusted hosts. Any suggestions would be very welcome, many thanks.

I continued my investigations. I setup a new project, new virtual environment and tried to update setuptools with:
python -m pip install setuptools==69.0.02

and got this error:
ERROR: HTTP error 400 while getting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/e1/ed2dd0850446b8697ad28d118df885ad04140c64ace06c4bd559f7c8a94f/setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/) (requir
es-python:>=3.8)
ERROR: Could not install requirement setuptools==69.0.02 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/e1/ed2dd0850446b8697ad28d118df885ad04140c64ace06c4bd559f7c8a94f/setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl because of HTTP error 400
Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/e1/ed2dd0850446b8697ad28d118df885ad04140c64ace06c4bd559f7c8a94f/setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl for URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/e1
/ed2dd0850446b8697ad28d118df885ad04140c64ace06c4bd559f7c8a94f/setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/) (requires-python:>=3.8)

my Python version is 3.8 so why the requires-python:>=3.8 Error?

Comment: Is your django version 1.3? Also what's your python version?

Comment: I updated my initial Post. Best

Comment: Did you Install pyodbc 3.0 (or newer) ?

Comment: yes, pyodbc 4.0.35

Comment: OK please take a look at https://pypi.org/project/mssql-django/ to be sure you're following every procedure and then `pip install mssql-django` or `python -m pip install mssql-django`

Comment: thanks for your suggestions but I still haven't found anything to solve my issue (I updated my Post with more information).